# finding solution to $u_x + 2u_y + (2x − y)u = 2x^2 + 3xy − 2y^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I tried to solve this equation with the coordinate method but I got  a bit different answer compared to the suggested one by the solution manual. 
Where I am making the mistake in my solution?

My attempt 
I chose the following coordinates 
$$\xi=2x-y$$
$$\nu=x$$

After substitution into the given equation I got the following equation
$$(2u_{\xi} + u_{\nu})+2(-u_{\xi}+0)+ (2x-y)u=2x^2 + 3xy - 2y^2  $$

which gives
$$u_{\nu}+ \xi u = 5 \nu \xi - 2 \xi^2$$

multiplying both sides by $e^{\xi \nu}$ and using the product rule I got
$$(e^{\xi \nu} u)_{\nu} =(5 \nu \xi - 2 \xi^2)e^{\xi \nu}$$

integrating both sides with respect to $\nu$ 
$$e^{\xi \nu} u =(5 \nu \xi - 2 \xi^2) \frac{1}{\xi} e^{\xi \nu}-\frac{5}{\xi} e^{\xi \nu} + f(\xi)$$
$$u=5\nu-2\xi-\frac{5}{\xi}+e^{-\xi \nu} f(\xi)$$

substituting for x and y
$$u(x,y)=5x-2(2x-y)-\frac{5}{2x-y}+f(2x-y)e^{-x(2x-y)}$$
which finally gives the general solution
$$u(x,y)= x + 2y \color{red}{-\frac{5}{2x-y} + f(2x-y) e^{xy-2x^2}}$$

but this is different from the one suggested by the solution manual
$$u = x + 2y + \frac{5}{y − 2x} + f(y−2x) e^{\frac{−2x^2 − 3xy + 2y^2}{5}} $$

**where is the mistake in my solution? 

does one should get always the same solution regardless of the coordinates chosen?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result is correct and the result of the book is also correct.

Strange isn't it ? Not at all : just a matter of symbolism for two functions each one being ANY function.

[image]

$$\frac{-2x^2-3xy+2y^2}{5} = (xy-2x^2)+\frac{2}{5}(y-2x)^2$$

$$e^{\frac{-2x^2-3xy+2y^2}{5}} = e^{\frac{2}{5}(y-2x)^2} e^{xy-2x^2}$$
$e^{\frac{2}{5}(y-2x)^2}$ is a function of $(y-2x)\quad$. Let $g(y-2x)=e^{\frac{2}{5}(y-2x)^2}$

$$f(y-2x)e^{\frac{-2x^2-3xy+2y^2}{5}} =f(y-2x)g(y-2x)e^{xy-2x^2}$$

Since $f$ is any function, $f(y-2x)g(y-2x)$ is any function of $(y-2x)\quad$.

Let $F(y-2x)=f(y-2x)g(y-2x)$

$$f(y-2x)e^{\frac{-2x^2-3xy+2y^2}{5}} =F(y-2x)e^{xy-2x^2}$$

$$u(x,y)=x+2y-\frac{5}{2x-y}+f(y-2x)e^{\frac{-2x^2-3xy+2y^2}{5}} =$$
$$=x+2y+\frac{5}{y-2x}+F(y-2x)e^{xy-2x^2}$$
This is exactly your result , except the symbol $F$ instead of your symbol $f$ . But they are equivalent because $F$ and $f$ are ANY function.